# How many Pit Vipents do I need to kill to finish the Snake Hunt quest in Perfect World?

Tags: perfect-world

I'm trying to complete the Snake Hunt quest given by the Sentry outside Hidden Heroes Village.  The quest is to kill as many Pit Vipents as you can in 30 minutes and report back.  I found the spot to hunt the Pit Vipents and I killed a ton of them in 30 minutes, but I still failed the quest.  How many of these things do I have to kill to complete the quest?

I did a general search before asking here, and the other posts I've found just repeat the instructions that you get in game.

Answer (score 3):

I may have been asking the wrong question.  I just completed the quest by killing 40 Pit Vipents, but I know I've killed that many in failed attempts before.  It looks like the key is to go kill some Pit Vipents east of the town, and **report back to the Sentry before your 30 minutes are up.**  If you're still out hunting when the timer expires, you automatically fail the quest.